# Why don't my female dwellers give birth to children?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am playing Fallout Shelter on my IPad. There were some women who have already gave birth, but two female dwellers are carrying their babies for about 18(!) hours. I know that this process takes three hours, so this is not normal. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have enough housing for the babies? According to the in-game help, babies will wait to be born if you don't have enough room.

Comment: @twobugs "Guess since nobody wants to give me my own room, I'm just gonna stay in here a while"....

Comment: @twobugs Yeah, there's plenty of space, it's not about that

Comment: [Read this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a1ahr/pregnant_dweller_for_more_than_24h/) and tell us if you moved the living quarters the babies were made in?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, I think it's true, I have made some redesign and I have moved the living quarters. So what can I do? Am I stuck with them forever?

Comment: Try to put back the living quarters where it was. Or put a new one were the old one was, might also work. There's no workaround that I could find as of now. Both those are my ideas about a possible workaround.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Ok, I'll try to remember where it was. Thank you! Hopefully Bethesda will fix it.

Comment: Define "plenty of space"? Are you saying that  you have enough spaces for all of them to work? That's not enough, and you need to make sure you have living quarters for all of them. If you touch the gear (upper left corner) that shows all of your dwellers, it will say "43/44" (which is what mine says currently) saying that I have enough living quarters for 44 people. If more than 1 person joins/is born, I will have to construct more living quarters for them to have a place to live. (Or upgrade existing living quarters.)

Comment: Today there is a new version release which fixes this bug. But I'm at the vault maximum which causes the same issue for me. I have a perma-pregnant. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Do you have many dead people in your vault?

Due to the fact, that a dead dweller can be revived even 24 hours after his dead, you cannot get above the limit with a new born child.

Just an example of that what I mean:

- Your vault maximum is 38 dwellers.
- You have 30 alive dwellers, 8 dead dwellers and 2 pregnant dwellers
- If the birth would happen, you would have 32 alive dwellers (of which are 0 pregnant and 2 children). You would have 6 dwellers left to your maximum capacity.
- If you would revive all of the 8 dead dwellers, you would have 40 out of 38 allowed dwellers.

Maybe this gives you a hint and maybe this is your case too.

The idea of the dead father won't work. I have also some new born which had a dead father. The icon of the father was just a grave, but it was found. The birth take place and everything else was normal. But well, it still could be a rare bug.

Comment: If this answer hasn't solved this problem then I guess its a bug. Contact the developer so they can fix this.

Comment: In some cases it was a bug, right. But not in all. :-) Today there is a new version release which fixes this bug. But I'm at the vault maximum which causes the same issue for me. I have a perma-pregnant. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because the father of the unborn baby is dead.

When the baby becomes born, the father cannot be found to be listed, so the game doesn't progress to prevent a crash.

Comment: Hmm, I am pretty sure that nobody has died while my play. Oh! Maybe that's because I have changed the name of some dwellers?

Comment: Read that dead dads aren't the cause of this but moving the living quarters might.

Comment: I've had women give birth while the dad's were dead.

Comment: @Sterno were the dads dead as in their corpse was still around waiting to be revived, or dead as in completely gone?

Comment: Waiting to be revived. Didn't realize the answer meant dead *and* removed. I could see that case.

Comment: So the answer to all these duplicate questions about permanent pregnancy is that it's a bug?

Comment: No this should't be the solution. I had seen it at friends and on my own. Even if the father is dead, everything works fine.

Comment: Why would the game necessarily crash if the father were dead?  Do you have a source that this is a known bug?