# Why won't 4 women give birth?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I made 5 women pregnant, but only one gave birth. My vault can fit 34 dwellers and I only have 27 (31 if the babies would be born).

Why won't the remaining 4 women give birth?

Comment: I haven't this situation. Normally if you have enough space they should give you the childrens. Just as an idea. Build another barrack. Maybe this will reset the timers.

Comment: Link to similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223916/112231

Comment: [Read this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a1ahr/pregnant_dweller_for_more_than_24h/) and tell us if you moved the living quarters the babies were made in?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **living quarters**, this expands the number of people you can have.

I had waited for 6 hours for 11 pregnant women to give birth - as soon as I put in a few living quarters I had 11 births within 3 minutes.