# A pregnancy in a full vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I filled my vault (without really paying attention, it just sort of happened) and I was fairly OK with hitting 200 dwellers.

And... so I wasn't paying full attention to which rooms I was assigning dwellers and I ended up with a male and a female dweller in the barracks... and well... I have a full vault and a pregnant dweller.

So, my question is; what happens now? 
Will she remain pregnant until there is space?
Will the baby be born and push me over the limit, presumably with some penalty for going over?
Will one of my other dweller die?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nobody will die, and you won't cross the limit. Your dweller will remain pregnant until there is space.

Similar question here: [Why don't my female dwellers give birth to children?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223916/why-dont-my-female-dwellers-give-birth-to-children)

Comment: This happened to me when I first hit the 200 limit. I ended up having to make a difficult decision -- the "sacrificial lamb" new guy got sent out to the wasteland with no stims or weapon. He didn't last long. Then came the painstaking effort of ensuring no living quarters had both sexes.