# I accidentally got pregnant, is there a way to become unpregnant?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I am already at the population cap for my vault - 200 dwellers - but while I was switching dwellers around rooms, I left two very charismatic dwellers in their living quarters together for too long, and now one of them is pregnant.

Since I'm at the population cap, what happens? Presumably my dweller will remain permanently pregnant now?

Answer (score 5):

As of the answer we have got over [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224365/80141) it is indeed implicated that the lady dweller will stay pregnant. At [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168521-fallout-shelter/72141100) it is also noted and confirmed that the dwellers will stay permanently pregnant.

Comment: So I have to kill someone to become unpregnant?

Comment: afaik pregnant dwellers cannot be killed, so I think so.

Comment: Well, allow someone *else* to die (I find deliberately sending a weak dweller unarmed into the wasteland is an effective way to do this, although the first one I sent happened to collect some good stuff so I ended up sending another), that way the baby can be born and you'll return to the 200 cap.